# Download File via FTP & Include Filesize

Tags: c#, ftp

I wrote this C# code but how can I get the filesize of the file I want to download from my FTP server and begin a download?

At the moment, my code fails to calculate the percentage and it is completely incorrect because I cannot get the filesize of the file I want to download.

If I change `request2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;` to `request2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;` I then manage to pull the filesize, but downloading stops working. Is there a way to do both?

```
FtpWebRequest request2 = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://username@127.0.0.1/myfile.zip");
request2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
FtpWebResponse response2 = (FtpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
responseStream = response2.GetResponseStream();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    //Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

    // get the current date as DD-MMM-YYYY
    DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now;
    string fdate = String.Format("{0:dd_MMM_yyyy}", dt);
    string fdate2 = fdate.ToUpper(); // convert to uppercase

    int length = (int)request2.GetResponse().ContentLength;
    //double length = response2.ContentLength;
    long downloaded = 0;
    long result = 0;
    int bufferSize = 32 * 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    using (FileStream writer = new FileStream("MYFILE" + fdate2 + ".ZIP", FileMode.Create))
    {
        Console.Write("\n\rMYFILE.ZIP = {0:N0} Bytes ({1:N0} Megabytes).\n", length, length/1024); // format the filesize with a comma
        Console.Write("NOTE: Press [CTRL+C] to cancel and terminate this program at anytime...\n\n");

        int readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (readCount > 0)
        {
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount); // byte

            readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            downloaded += readCount; // increment

            double dProgress = ((double)downloaded / length) * 100.0;
            result = Convert.ToInt32(dProgress);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write("\r   DOWNLOADING 1/1... {0}%", result);
        }
    }

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nDownload Complete! STATUS: {0}", response2.StatusDescription);

    reader.Close();
}
```

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the file size and download the file using FTP in C#, you can make separate requests to obtain the file size and then perform the download

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ftpUrl = "ftp://username@127.0.0.1/myfile.zip";
        string localFilePath = "MYFILE.zip";

        long fileSize = GetFileSize(ftpUrl);
        if (fileSize > 0)
        {
            DownloadFile(ftpUrl, localFilePath, fileSize);
            Console.WriteLine("Download Complete!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve file size.");
        }
    }

    static long GetFileSize(string ftpUrl)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            return response.ContentLength;
        }
    }

    static void DownloadFile(string ftpUrl, string localFilePath, long fileSize)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
                int bytesRead;
                long totalBytesRead = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                    double progress = (double)totalBytesRead / fileSize * 100.0;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded: {progress:F2}%");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this updated code, the `GetFileSize` method sends a `WebRequest` with the method `GetFileSize` to retrieve the size of the file. Then, the `DownloadFile` method performs the actual file download using the `DownloadFile` method of `FtpWebRequest`. The progress calculation has also been adjusted to display the correct percentage based on the file size.